# mouse hover on drawn shapes of a qgraphicsitem pyqt4

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4, qgraphicsitem

I have a QGraphicsItem with drawn shapes (below image). How do I detect if the mouse pointer is over the circle, the text or the green rect? All shapes were drawn using the painter method (i.e.: painter.drawText()).

[image]

Would be possible make this using a QGraphicsItem into its parent (also a QGraphicsItem) and use the hover mouse events?

Answer (score 0):

The solution you suggested is the easiest approach--rather than draw all of the circles from a single GraphicsItem, make each circle its own GraphicsItem and make them children of the original GraphicsItem. Then you can handle mouse hover events individually for each circle.